Kill Tomcat blocked threads
I developed a Java app running on Tomcat 9. Sometimes happens that a software problem causes blocking one or more Tomcat threads, threads remain blocked indefinitely:

Is there a solution to kill these threads or to configure a maxtime of life?
Thank you.
